# Trying to update an entity using EF and send it using WCF - property is causing an exception in an update scenario

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to send an object using WCF. The object is retrieved from the DB using EF.

This is the exception I get:

[image]

This only happens in an update scenario. Insert works perfectly.
Tracking the bug, I found that the problem is with a collection (called `Travelers`) I added recently.

Here is what happens when I try to watch its value at runtime, after updating, before sending the updated entity by WCF:

[image]

Here's the offending class' property declaration (I tried uncommenting the `DataMember` attribute but it didn't work):

```
[DataContract]
public class Travel : InsuredObject, ISaleEntity, ICloneable
{    
    //[DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Traveler> Travelers { get; set; } 
    ...
```

I've read that `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` and/or `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` might fix it, but I can't change those for reasons beyond me, and even when I tried playing with them - I got some other exceptions...

**Additional Code:**
The update method:

```
public virtual TEntity CreateAndUpdate(int saleId, TEntity entity) {
    var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext;

    var objBaseSet = context.CreateObjectSet<TBase>();

    var entityBaseKey = context.CreateEntityKey(objBaseSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);
    Object foundBaseEntity;
    var baseExists = context.TryGetObjectByKey(entityBaseKey, out foundBaseEntity);

    entity.Id = saleId;

    if (!baseExists) {
        this.GetDbSet<TEntity>().Add(entity); 
    }

    this.objectContext.SaveChanges();

    return entity;
}
```

Retrieving the containing object before updating:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, bool brutalRefresh = false) {

    IQueryable<TEntity> retObj = this.GetDbSet<TEntity>();
    if (where != null) {
        retObj = retObj.Where(where);
    }

    if (brutalRefresh) {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext;
        context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, retObj);
    }

    return retObj;
}
```

...All that code is common code with other projects, that send and receive the same entity as I do, it's just the `Travel` entity I added, that causes me problems, so the solution I'm looking for should consist of 0 changes in common code..

`Traveler` Class(fully):

```
 [DataContract]
    public class Traveler : ISaleEntity, ICloneable
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string IDNumber { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<SelectedCoverage> SelectedCoverages { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<MedicalQuestionnaireAnswer> MedicalQuestionnaireAnswers
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers))
                    return new List<MedicalQuestionnaireAnswer>();

                return DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers.Split(',')
                    .Select(c => (MedicalQuestionnaireAnswer)int.Parse(c)).ToList();
            }
            set { DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers = string.Join(",", value.Select(m => (int)m)); }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public Genders Gender
        {
            get { return (Genders)DBGender; }
            set { DBGender = (int)value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// NOTE! Do not use this property directly! use MedicalQuestionnaireAnswers instead
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// NOTE! Do not use this property directly! use Gender instead
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public int DBGender { get; set; }

        public object Clone()
        {
            Traveler traveler = new Traveler();
            traveler.FirstName = this.FirstName;
            traveler.LastName = this.LastName;
            traveler.IDNumber = this.IDNumber;
            traveler.BirthDate = this.BirthDate;
            traveler.DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers = this.DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers;
            traveler.Gender = this.Gender;
            if (this.SelectedCoverages != null)
            {
                traveler.SelectedCoverages = this.SelectedCoverages.Select(sc => (SelectedCoverage)sc.Clone()).ToList();
            }

            return traveler;
        }
    }

    public static class TravelerExtension
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// copy all the property except from the id and src defualt values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbTraveler"></param>
        /// <param name="src"></param>
        public static void CopyTravelerProperties(this Traveler target, Traveler src)
        {
            target.FirstName = src.FirstName;
            target.LastName = src.LastName;
            target.IDNumber = src.IDNumber;
            target.BirthDate = src.BirthDate;
            target.DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers = src.DBMedicalQuestionnaireAnswers;
            target.DBGender = src.DBGender;
            target.SelectedCoverages.CopySelectedCoveragesProperties(src.SelectedCoverages);
        }
    }

    public static class TravelersExtension
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// copy all the property except from the id and src defualt values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbTravelers"></param>
        /// <param name="src"></param>
        public static void CopyTravelersProperties(this ICollection<Traveler> target, ICollection<Traveler> src)
        {

            List<int> allTravelersIdsSrc = src.Select(t => t.Id).ToList();

            // remove ids exist target and not in src 
            target.ToList().RemoveAll(t => allTravelersIdsSrc.Contains(t.Id));


            target = target ?? new List<Traveler>();
            foreach (Traveler srcTraveler in src)
            {
                var targetTraveler = target.FirstOrDefault(targetTrv => srcTraveler.Id != 0 && targetTrv.Id == srcTraveler.Id);
                // if not exist traveler with target traveler id in db
                if (targetTraveler == null)
                {
                    // add srcTraveler to target
                    target.Add(srcTraveler);
                }
                else
                {
                    targetTraveler.CopyTravelerProperties(srcTraveler);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Further info:**
The immediate window exception does not occur if calling `ToList()` prior to trying to get the value in the immediate window. The problem itself persists though.

Trying to comment the `[DataMember]` attribute on:

```
public virtual ICollection<SelectedCoverage> SelectedCoverages { get; set; }
```

in `Traveler` class had no impact.

The exception:

[image]

**Further info 2:**

There is just 1 entity that causes the exception:

```
public class Quote : ISaleEntity, ICloneable {      
    ...
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Travel Travel { get; set; } 
    ...
```

When i change the above `[DataMember]` to `[IgnoreDataMember]` - no exception.

I set all the properties of this class to `[IgnoreDataMember]`

```
[DataContract]
    public class Travel : InsuredObject, ISaleEntity, ICloneable
    {
         [IgnoreDataMember]
        //[DataMember]
        public bool? IsFromIsrael { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        //[DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Traveler> Travelers { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }

          [IgnoreDataMember]
        //[DataMember]
        [NotMapped]
        public List<int> DestinationsCodes
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DBDestinationsCodes))
                    return new List<int>();

                return DBDestinationsCodes.Split(',').Select(c => int.Parse(c)).ToList();
            }

            set { DBDestinationsCodes = string.Join(",", value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// NOTE! Do not use this property directly! use DestinationsCodes instead
        /// </summary>
             [IgnoreDataMember]
        //[DataMember]
        public string DBDestinationsCodes { get; set; }
        ...
```

But the exception still occurs. Probably because of the class this class inherits from:

```
[DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Vehicle))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Apartment))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Travel))]
    public class InsuredObject : ISaleEntity, ICloneable {
        [Key]
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int? OwnerTypeId { get; set; }


        //navigation property

        [DataMember]
        public bool? HasShiabud { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual Shiabud Shiabud { get; set; }

        //[NotMapped]
        //public virtual Proposal Proposal { get; set; }

        //[DataMember]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Coverage> Coverages { get; set; }  
        ...
```

So how can I send this entity via WCF?

Comment: If you (temporarily) call `ToList()` on `Travelers` before saving, does the error go away?

Comment: That's curious.  Generally, the approach for dealing with this issue is as answered by @WicherVisser (or alternatively using `Include(...)`, [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19928165/1197605)), for which calling `ToList()` is a good test.  Could you also post your `Traveler` class?  Perhaps there is something about it that is triggering the exception.  You might also try setting the VS option to break on thrown exceptions (as opposed to just unhandled) and see if anything else is getting thrown prior to that.

Comment: @cokeman19 thanks a lot. I just re-checked and it seems the exception that was thrown in the immediate window, is not thrown when I use ToList() (but the problem itself is unchanged). Not sure what that means, but at least got a tiny bit more info to work with

Comment: Tried to  set the VS option to break on thrown exceptions, the first time this exception is thrown is on the prop = client.SaveGeneralDetails(..) line

Comment: I think you're on the right track with `SelectedCoverages` property, as I still believe the issue is related to lazy loading.  It might be worth a try to call `ToList()` on this also (as well as accessing any & all virtual sub-properties).  If that has no effect, try systematically commenting out the `Traveler`'s properties; there should be a point at which the error goes away.  Also, are there any inner exceptions for the "The underlying connection was closed" error?

Comment: added the exception details. Is commenting the DataMember attribute enough, or should I comment the entire property (for each property. That would be a bit tricky, since I'm using EF which will mean a ton of migrations, and since the web page will not display properly, which mean many code fixes as well..). Also, thinking about it, I can't ToList() SelectedCoverages etc., since there are 0 travelers. I removed them all in code!

Comment: In that case, instead of commenting them out I would: 1) Replace `[DataMember]` with `[IgnoreDataMember]` on each property. 2) Explicitly set the `[NotMapped]` attribute on each property, as well as removing the `virtual` keyword.  This way nothing is assumed by either EF or the DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Pretty sure this is due to the lazy loading feature of EF. Can you post what the code of SaveGeneralDetails looks like?

Comment: @cokeman19 Thanks yet again! More info, still no solution :-/

Comment: @RominNoodleSamurai It's quite enormous.. Lazy loading is set to false at the context class (and I can't change that..). Anything specific I can share that would be helpful?

Comment: It looks like you're close to narrowing it down.  Another option is to walk backwards through the call stack, looking at the Locals pane; more specifically, those frames starting with `EntityFramework`.  In one of the frames it should show you which member specifically is problematic.  At this point, since the context-level options aren't viable for you, you're just looking for which member(s) to call `Include` on.

Comment: A possible reasons are that maximum HTTP message size or timeout is exceeded - these issues yield alike exceptions. I think it worth to sniff the produced HTTP message, e.g. by Fiddler, and post here (directly or by link to Pastebin). To check the timeout, you can increase it to maximum inside WCF binding.

Answer (score 1):

By making your properties Virtual, what you are doing is lazy loading.

You can make properties into ICollection instead, and do eager loading instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the part of your code with the EF context that does the DB update?

From the error message I gather that it is not WCF that is playing tricks. Rather, it appears that the EF ObjectContent has been disposed by the time you are applying your changes (the SaveChanges() method). This can happen if you keep it alive between WCF method calls, e.g. having it as a static variable in your backend and having it in a using-clause.

This should work to apply lazy-loading to your DB context for EF 6 and newer, though it works similarly for older versions. (I implemented a inherited class to help deal with the configurations. This may not be required)

```
public class DomainDbContext : DbContext
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I updated the question, and now trying to understand what all you wrote means :) :(. It seems that SaveChanges happens before sending wcf..

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: 5. need more chars, so I'll say I used the appropriate tag in the question.

Comment: where is your ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext used? It looks like "this.Context" has been disposed by another method.

Comment: I've just spent almost 3 hrs trying to find that, and trying to rewrite handling the problematic collection, including disposing the context myself. no success in either. Could you give me any direction? It's just an empty list that keeps causing that bug..

Comment: Can you share your solution with me?